# tax implications of selling US stock while living in the EU (Germany)

Tags: germany, taxes

I've found this surprisingly difficult to get a good answer on, but what are the tax liabilities for selling US stocks or ETFs if you're a US citizen living abroad for the long term?

I live in Germany and am not sure if I will be double-charged for selling securities, and my online brokers declined to provide any information, stating that they can't keep up with every country's policies.

If anyone has experience with this and can provide a general account of what to expect or links to information in English or German, I would be grateful. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think there'd be a difference depending upon where the US taxpayer resides?

Comment: @David a US citizen who incurs a capital gain or loss while residing in the US has potential tax liability only in the US, but if the US citizen resides in Germany there is potential tax liability in both the US and Germany.  (As far as I'm aware, it did not matter that the capital asset is US stock.)

Comment: You're right; I was considering only the taxpayer's US obligation, which wouldn't change depending on their residence. I know zip about German tax law, and there may well be a German obligation here as well.